# Git - Why it's better to use 'git pull --rebase' instead of just 'git pull'

Tags: git

I'm just wondering what are more reasons to use `git pull --rebase` instead of `git pull` except this weird merge commits that appear when you do just `git pull`? Thanks!

Comment: Where you want your own local commits to be applied on top of the public history - have you done any research for your question?

Comment: It's better to use `fetch` + `merge`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804115/git-rebase-vs-git-merge?rq=1

Comment: @zerkms you probably meant fetch + rebase given the question. It's not "pull v fetch+merge" but "rebase v merge"

Comment: I meant ``git fetch`` and then ``git pull --rebase`` I worked with my collegues on one branch with small updates, and it works fine

Comment: @AD7six: nope, `fetch` + `merge`. `Rebase` may cause controversial automatic merges which you won't be able to explain after. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/52638/2014/5/14/1-3 --- here is a discussion where I provided a proof for what I'm talking about

Comment: @zerkms so your answer to "why/when is it better to pull --rebase instead of git pull" is "Don't use rebase ever"? That conversation is too long to see whatever it is you're trying to point out - but I disagree that rebase has no place in git (which is how I read your last comment).

Comment: @AD7six As I understand ``merge`` will produce additional commit

Comment: @Kosmetika yes it will. That's not the only difference, or even the main difference though.

Comment: @AD7six: that's correct - my answer for the given question is "Please don't, use `fetch` + `merge` instead". As I said, `rebase` may cause the output that no one will be able to explain, unless you know it might be introduced by a `rebase`, which is not the case since there are no traces of `rebase` after it's done.

Comment: @AD7six in my experience ``fetch`` and ``git pull --rebase`` worked fine all the time, any unexpected conflicts etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git pull` is really just shorthand for

```
git fetch
git merge
```

Now, if you your branch has changed independent of the upstream version you are pulling, the history of your branch will now have branching in it (use `gitk` for a simple visualization).

However, if you use `git pull --rebase`, git will try to rebase your changes on top of the changes from the upstream source, retaining a linear commit history, which is generally preferable for clarity and other git history manipulations.